# Using AWS MemoryDB with Go Redis client

Tags: go, redis, amazon-memory-db

I am using [go-redis](https://github.com/redis/go-redis) library to use AWS MemoryDB cluster as a database.

I am able to connect to cluster with VPN connection, however

the following cli command connects to database:

`redis-cli --tls -u redis://<memory-db-endpoint> -p 6379`

but the following Go code does not work and get `i/o timeout` error.

```golang
conf, err := redis.ParseURL("redis://$CLUSTER_ENDPOINT:6379")
if err != nil {
   panic(err)
}

cl := redis.NewClient(conf)
res, err := cl.Ping(context.Background()).Result()
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

what is needed to establish a connection with a single node AWS MemoryDB cluster?

Comment: Are you literally passing `"redis://$CLUSTER_ENDPOINT:6379"`, or are you just redacting `$CLUSTER_ENDPOINT`?

Answer (score 2):

Redis URIs with TLS must begin with "rediss://", not "redis://"; see https://www.iana.org/assignments/uri-schemes/prov/rediss for more information.

This code works:

```
conf, err := redis.ParseURL("rediss://$CLUSTER_ENDPOINT:6379")
if err != nil {
   panic(err)
}

cl := redis.NewClient(conf)
res, err := cl.Ping(context.Background()).Result()
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `go-redis` library does not know how to get system certificates for TLS connections.

So, here is how to pass system certificate pool to connection config.

```golang
...

pool, err := x509.SystemCertPool()
if err != nil {
   panic(err)
}

conf.TLSConfig = &tls.Config{
    RootCAs: pool,
}

...
```